# Implementing a Neural Network

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

TLDR: I am implementing a neural net in Mathematica and need help with back propagation.

This is purely for the joy of implementing a neural network with a functional programming language. If someone is reading this with the serious intention of using a neural net in Mathematica, it's [built in to version 11](https://www.wolfram.com/language/11/neural-networks/).

I started by implementing a neuron as a list containing a value and the weights of incoming edges, layers as lists of neurons, and networks as lists of layers.

```
Neuron[i_] := {0}~Join~((2*RandomReal[] - 1) & /@ Range[i]);
Neuron[v_, w_] := Join[{v}, w];
Layer[n_, i_] := Array[Neuron[i] &, n];
Network[i_, h_, o_] := {Layer[i, 0], Layer[h, i], Layer[o, h]};
```

I then implemented a function to pass an input into the network.

```
Compute[network_, inputs_] := Fold[#1~Join~{Compute[#2, Last[#1]]} &, {MapThread[Join[{#1}, #2] &, {inputs, Rest /@ First[network]}]}, Rest[network]] /; Depth[network] == 4;

Compute[layer_, values_] := Compute[#, values] & /@ layer /; Depth[layer] == 3;

Compute[neuron_, value_] := {LogisticSigmoid[Total[MapThread[#1*First[value[[#2]]] &, {Rest[neuron], Range[Length[neuron] - 1]}]]]} ~Join~ Rest[neuron] /; Depth[neuron] == 2;
```

I'm having difficulties with back propagation. I implemented what I believe is correct based on studying other code I've written on [this gist](https://gist.github.com/keshavsaharia/369951a12508c49d7b587027323fa7e9) and pasted below, but would greatly appreciate either code examples or general pushes in the right direction.

```
Propagate[network_, output_, learningRate_] :=
  With[{
     outputLayer = MapThread[
       Propagate[#1, network[[2]], #2, learningRate] &,
       {Last[network], output}],
     hiddenLayer = network[[2]],
     inputLayer = First[network]
     },
    {inputLayer, MapIndexed[Propagate[#1, First[#2],
        inputLayer, outputLayer, output, learningRate] &, 
      hiddenLayer], outputLayer}
    ] /; Depth[network] == 4;

Propagate[neuron_, hiddenLayer_, target_, learningRate_] :=

  Join[{NeuronValue[neuron]},
   MapThread[
    #1 - learningRate*
       -NeuronValue[neuron]*(1 - NeuronValue[neuron])*
       (target - NeuronValue[neuron])*#2 &,
    {NeuronWeights[neuron], LayerValues[hiddenLayer]}]
   ];

Propagate[neuron_, index_, inputLayer_, outputLayer_, target_, 
  learningRate_] :=
 Join[{NeuronValue[neuron]},
  MapIndexed[
   #1 - learningRate*
      NeuronValue[neuron]*(1 - NeuronValue[neuron])*
      NeuronValue[inputLayer[[First[#2]]]]*
      Total[MapThread[(#3 - #1)*-1*#1*(1 - #1)*#2 &, {
         LayerValues[outputLayer],
         LayerWeights[outputLayer, index],
         target}]] &,
   NeuronWeights[neuron]]]
```

Comment: From May 1994, Simulating Neural Networks with Mathematica by James A. Freeman (  https://goo.gl/bsl2pg  )

Answer (score 9):

All those API's are way too complicated. Modern Neural Networks are essentially a chain of matmuls or convolutions interleaved with pointwise non-linearity function like sigmoid or ReLU. Such simple architectures rival the super-complicated ones (see this [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1611.04231))

You can define a loss of a simple feed forward neural network as follows:

```
vars = (* list of symbolic matrices *)
relu[A_] := 
 MapThread[Max, {Array[0 &, Dimensions@A], A}, Length[Dimensions[A]]]
reluDot[A_, B_] := relu[A.B];
errEq := Y - Fold[reluDot, Reverse[vars]];
lossEq := take1[1/(2 dsize) errEq.errEq\[Transpose]];
```

You can then use Mathematica's differentiation to minimize `lossEq` which is your neural network training. There needs to be some extra book-keeping for dealing with symbolic matrices, one approach is to define them using `Array[]` construct and then use `./` to substitute actual values, a full example is here:
https://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/e8cc8432-d38e-4d38-ab79-57d778a97997

Answer (score 4):

After dissecting the code I noted that the functions `NeuronValue`, `NeuronWeights`, `LayerWeights`, and `LayerValues` are not defined in `$Version` 11.0.1, so I could not replicate your problem. If you are using the additional Neural Network Package that is not included with Mathematica you could contact the creator of the package [Jonas Sjöberg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4300153/jonas-sj%C3%B6berg) directly using the [product's home page](https://www.wolfram.com/products/applications/neuralnetworks/whofor.html).  Using the following function definition format could make the code easier to follow.

```
context`functionName[param_?HeadQ:defaultValue /; param_[comparison]paramThresholdValue ]:= BuiltInFunction[param];(* Comment *)  context`functionName::usage="Description of input and output types.";
```

[image: DISSECT_1]
[image: DISSECT_2]
[image: DISSECT_3]